# Android, Does INVISIBLE View use device resources?

Tags: android, view

I have a heavy layout for my `RecyclerView` rows. I know that `GONE` Views are not using CPU and RAM but what about `INVISIBLE` Views?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you have seen/read that `GONE` Views are **not** using CPU and RAM, because while it's available in your layout and it has a memory mapping in `R.java` so it still **consume resources**.

But it consume **less** thant `VISIBLE` or `INVISIBLE` because it doesn't need to call `onMeasure()` or `onDraw()`.

---

To sum up:

- `INVISIBLE` Views consume device resources.
- `GONE` Views also consume device resources, but **less** than `VISIBLE` or `INVISIBLE`.